# Fonts not installed on server

Tags: fonts, jvm, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper reports for reports generation. I got error saying "Fonts not available to JVM". I resolved that by installing required fonts in my system and works fine. But when i deployed it on server and try running it, its started giving the same error...! Can anyone tell me how to fix it.? 
Thanks

Comment: For clarity - have you installed the required fonts on the server?

Answer (score 1):

The prototypical example is when a developer uses Arial while developing a report in iReport on Windows, then the report fails to run when deployed to JasperReports Server on Linux. One solution is to install the fonts on the OS wherever you will run the report.

A much better solution is to use Font Extensions. This is the JasperReports mechanism to ensure you have the fonts that you need. I wrote an article about [font extensions](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/jaspersoft-v3-7-font-extensions/) a couple of years ago. That's a good place to start. The JasperReports documentation talks about it as well.

Comment: Well Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/8373/mdahlman for your response. I resolved the issue. Just add the below line to *.jrxml file <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font" value="true"/>.. Simple as this! enjoy

Comment: Yep, if you don't mind what font gets used, then that's the simple solution. But often when someone specifies a font in the report, he really wants to use it.